# Transfer of objects by the method parameter ATL C ++

Tags: c++, com, atl, ole

Hi I try return my OLE object  (SerwerError) like this :

```
[propget, id(2)] HRESULT LastError([out, retval] IServerError* pVal);
```

but I get error :

```
syntax error : expecting a type specification near "IServerError"
```

I can't find resolution ... How Can i passing Ole Object ([in] / [out] )

[image: CServerError :]

Comment: You are showing a screen shot of a C++ class name CServerError.  C, not I.  What interfaces it implements or whether you forgot to #include an .h file is impossible to guess.

Comment: @HansPassant http://screenshot.sh/mKTX2EwR7ovDY

Answer (score 1):

`[out]` interface pointer parameter should be of a "pointer to interface pointer" type:

```
[out, retval] IServerError** pVal
```

That is, second asterisk. You will be returning `IServerError*` value. Then, `IServerError` interface itself should be defined early enough, so that it's a known type at the moment of method declaration.

Comment: i declared IServerError